# Issue in filtering rows for a range based on conditions from two columns in a data table in R

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, range

I have the following data table (DT) in R. I want to filter the rows for the range from "st_wk" and "end_wk" from the "attrib_wk" column by "Year" and "FIPS_Code".

```
result <- DT[which(DT[,st_wk] == DT[,attrib_wk ]), ]
```

But, I am unable to get the output shown below using the above code.
Can somebody please correct me to achieve the desired output for all the years and FIPS Codes?

Thank you.

```
DT: 
     Year FIPS_Code  attrib_wk rain_3wk   temp_3wk        st_wk        end_wk
     2006      1033     01-03  75.13333    49.41333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     01-04  78.83333    49.95333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     01-05  82.30000    49.03333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     02-01  83.06000    48.57667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     02-02  81.65000    44.40667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     02-03  80.01667    43.35333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     02-04  78.55333    42.79667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     02-05  77.32000    44.87333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     03-01  76.14333    47.79333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     03-02  75.34000    52.99333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     03-03  74.73000    56.61000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     03-04  75.58000    55.10333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     03-05  75.82667    52.63333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     04-01  75.67000    54.78667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     04-02  75.96333    59.22333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     04-03  75.56000    65.33000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     04-04  74.84667    68.44000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     04-05  73.46667    69.71000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     05-01  73.70333    69.04333       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     05-02  76.00000    67.20667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     05-03  77.26333    66.33000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     05-04  76.52333    67.79000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     05-05  72.71000    72.17000       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     06-01  69.16333    76.12667       05-01         05-04
     2006      1033     06-02  65.87000    77.30667       05-01         05-04

Output: (for one year: 2006)

 Year    FIPS_Code  attrib_wk rain_3wk   temp_3wk        st_wk        end_wk
 2006      1033     05-01     73.70333    69.04333       05-01         05-04
 2006      1033     05-02     76.00000    67.20667       05-01         05-04
 2006      1033     05-03     77.26333    66.33000       05-01         05-04
 2006      1033     05-04     76.52333    67.79000       05-01         05-04
```

Comment: Try with `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: I have tried that, but it did not work. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you looking for elementwise `==` comparison (attrib_wb` and `st_wk` only matches in some rows, `DT[attrib_wb == st_wk]` should have given the subset for all years, FIPs if there is a match for a row

Comment: rows selected from the "attrib_wk" column should be in the range from "st_wk" to "end_wk" for that FIPS and Year.

Comment: Then, you may need to convert to date class and do `>=` and `<=` with the columns

Comment: Is it `month-week` `05-01`?

Comment: yes. it is month-week

Answer (score 0):

You can try

library(dplyr)

```
DT %>% filter(attrib_wk == st_wk)
```

Comment: I tried this but this does not work. since it only filters attrib_wk == st_wk but I need to values in betwwen st_wk and end_wk

Comment: DT<- DT%>% mutate( my_range = ifelse(attrib_wk >= st_wk | attrib_wk <= st_wk, "my_range", "no_need"))
dat<- DT %>% filter(my_range== "my_range")

Comment: It does not provide the desired output. Have tried this.